# Android[Force Close]Is there a signal that i can know it is the 'Force Close' reason in the Log?

Tags: android

i'm facing a problem that i have to analysis Log,but it's too many(more than 30000 lines).my user told me that he got a Force close dialog when he's using my app. so is there a signal or a tag that can help me to find it more easily? now,my method is just searching by my app's package name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integrate [Bugsense](http://www.bugsense.com/) inside your app it will help you get all crash reports.

Answer (score 0):

If your application is on play store ask the user to report the issue and logs will reflect as crash report in the play store console for you application.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a simple search the package name of your app in the log to quickly locate the line.